# Extract first url or image from a webpage in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

Is there a way to extract any link from the URL of the page and open it in UIWebView.
I already know how to display a webpage on ios screen:

```
 [myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http:google.com]]]
```

Example: Suppose a string is given by the user "ABC". The code I want  to write should search say "ABC" in google and open the first link that it shows. <- This all to be done automatically. All that user care is give the input string.

Please help regarding the procedure and steps one should follow.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I undestood what you want, you can load the url content into a string

```
[NSString stringWithContentsOfUrl: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mydomain.com"] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error: nil];
```

and after that you need to know the html struct to extract the link (result) that you want. Eg: for google, you can find a div `<div id="ires">` that has `ol` and `li` elements that contains the links. So you just load the webview content with the result link, like you said above.

Comment: It was initially not getting any string in return value. I think there is an encoding error.
I removed the argument "encoding" and "error" and it worked for me. But instead I am getting a warning saying this function is deprecated in ios2.0